# Negative Testing Paypal DoExpressCheckoutPayment without code change

Tags: testing, paypal

I would like to test DoExpressCheckoutPayment without changing my code (otherwise I'm not really testing the proper code).  It seems I need to set the token to a certain error code, but that means changing the code and therefore not a proper test in my opinion.

Are there any alternative methods?  I am using NVP interface.

Answer (score 1):

As per the PayPal [Sandbox User Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf) (page 46), in order to test the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API, you can also set the `AMT` (or `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT`) parameter to a certain value to trigger an error condition.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  I tried with &AMT=106.23, but it didn't return an error.  I also have negative test mode enabled in the sandbox.  I am using API version 88

Comment: That link no longer exists, this is the new one: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/

Comment: I had to recreate my sandbox accounts in order to get negative testing to work properly earlier this week.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same error and after some debugging with paypal employees we found out that it might be related to 'Digital' products and that correct place to put the error code is `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` and format is `100.01` for `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`

So try setting `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=106.23` for your error. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To enable negative testing:

1. Login @ http://developer.paypal.com
2. Applications > Sandbox Accounts. You will have 1 Business type account and 0 or more Personal type accounts.
3. Under the Business account, click Profile > Settings, switch Negative Testing to On
4. When you send a request, send the relevant error code. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/